# How to scale gazebo garden camera_info with resolution

Tags: gazebo, camera, gazebo-camera, camera-info, image-geometry

for background, I'm detecting the pose of objects based on detected pixels using image_geometry. I've tested this code IRL with an oak-d and found it accurate against a ground truth, so it's working fine. When moving it to gazebo however, I noticed that detected objects seemed to be very off. Curiously, it seems that changing the camera resolution in gazebo effects this offset.

Example (1280 x 720):

[image]

(640 x 360):

[image]

While I am still rather novice to camera intrinsics, I feel like changing the camera resolution should not change detected locations (and indeed, IRL it does not). The camera_info from gazebo remains static this whole time, which makes me wonder if it should be changing. I feel like this is a bug in gazebo, but I wanted to reach out here first to see if I'm missing anything.

sensor:

```
    <gazebo reference="mid_cam_link">
        <sensor name="mid_cam_link" type="rgbd_camera">
          <camera>
            <horizontal_fov>1.204</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
              <width>1280</width>
              <height>720</height>
            </image>
            <clip>
              <near>0.1</near>
              <far>100</far>
            </clip>
              <depth_camera>
                  <clip>
                      <near>0.6</near>
                      <far>10</far>
                  </clip>
              </depth_camera>
          </camera>
          <always_on>1</always_on>
          <update_rate>30</update_rate>
          <visualize>true</visualize>
          <topic>mid_rgbd_camera</topic>
          <enable_metrics>true</enable_metrics>
            <gz_frame_id>mid_cam_link</gz_frame_id>
        </sensor>
  </gazebo>
```

camera_info for reference:

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 2
    nanosec: 113000000
  frame_id: mid_cam_link
height: 720
width: 1280
distortion_model: plumb_bob
d:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
k:
- 277.0
- 0.0
- 160.0
- 0.0
- 277.0
- 120.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0
r:
- 1.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0
p:
- 277.0
- 0.0
- 160.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 277.0
- 120.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 1.0
- 0.0
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi:
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: false
---
```